# Model Based Testing Tutorial with C# / .NET

Tags: c#, .net, testing, models, mbt

Is there any C# .NET resource from where I can learn about how to write Model Based Tests ?
using NModel or preferrably Spec Explorer ? just some basic tutorials on how to write MBT ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to take a look at some of the answers posted here:
http://testing.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-to-get-started-with-model-based-testing

Specifically for Spec Explorer you might want to take a look at the their [blog.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/specexplorer/)

Depending on how much experience you have with MBT you may want to look at some of the papers here on [Harry Robinson's](http://www.harryrobinson.net/) site

Answer (score 3):

I actually run a blog on model based testing, where I explore some of the applications and downsides of model based testing. It contains both some high level thoughts but also samples that you can have a look at for inspiration. It's newly started, so its not as content rich as I would prefer it, but it will get there.

You can find it at:
http://appmbt.blogspot.com/

Comment: Question is a bit out of date but its good to have a new resource.

Answer (score 0):

The best learning resource on model-based testing with NModel is accompanying book from the authors of the tool: *"Model-Based Software Testing and Analysis with C#"* by Colin Campbell, Baron Clyde, Jonathan Jacky, Margus Veanes, and Wolfram Schulte.

The book teaches more than just using NModel. It explains lots of theory behind the tool: methods and techniques to simulate and explore model, conduct safety and liveness analyses, conformance on-the-fly testing; which can be applied when using SpecExplorer too.